# python 2D array initialization, is there any actual runtime difference for the below ways

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is any difference between the following two initialization methods, when I try to use the first one, it got time limit exceed in leetcode, but the second one can run through...  (s is a string, basically, I want to initializa a 2D boolean array with length of s)

first:

```
dp = [[False for i in range(len(s))] for j in range(len(s))]
```

second:

```
dp = [[False] *(len(s)) for j in range(len(s))]
```

Thanks for any comments!!

Comment: This is faster ds = [[False] *len(s)] * len(s)

Comment: I believe these *two* methods created *different* things! ^^^

Comment: @Colim  The problem with your suggestion is that now each inner list is a reference to the same list object, so flipping any value to True in a row will update it in all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using the timeit module and using a size of 20 and 100,000 iterations, I got that the second option took about 25% of the time of the first option.
Working in the IDLE shell on Python 3.9.6:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(stmt='dp = [[False for i in range(s)] for j in range(s)]', setup='s=20', number=100000)
# Multiple runs giving results between 2.365 seconds and 2.870 seconds.

>>> timeit(stmt='dp = [[False] * s for j in range(s)]', setup='s=20', number=100000)
# Multiple runs giving results between 0.62 and 0.8 seconds.
```

What doesn't work is `dp = [[False] *len(s)] * len(s)`.  It will look like a 2D array, but each row will be referencing the same list object in memory, so an update to one row will affect all rows.

Comment: Just for completeness I ran one more comparison set with s = 200 for 500,000 iterations, and the difference is more pronounced.  Option 1 took 1471.3416 seconds, and Option 2 took 218.3876 seconds, or ~15% of the time of the first option.